# MS Access queries based on criteria in current table

Tags: ms-access

I am brand new to Access. I want to create a Table that summarizes all data from another table grouping items together using drop down menus. The source data will look something like this:

```
ItemCode |  Field1    |  Field2  
--------------------------------
001A     |    cat     |  1.5   
001B     |    mouse   |  11  
001C     |    frog    |  2.3  
002A     |    zebra   |  55  
002B     |    unicorn |  91  
002C     |    dragon  |  49
```

I want to create another table that has a drop down menu on each ItemCode cell for each set of codes (A, B or C) and populates the other fields accordingly.

```
ItemCode |  Field1    |  Field2  
--------------------------------
001A     |    cat     |  1.5   
002C     |    dragon  |  49
```

I thought that I should create a field with just the number component "001", "002" etc. in say Field 3, to create a list based on a query that would search for Field 3 and return the relevant ItemCode. However, Access doesn't let you use a query within a table that references another cell within it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do `cat` and `dragon` appear in your result set?

Comment: Right, if you select 001 from dropdown, why would cat return and not mouse or frog? Or if you pick A from a dropdown, why cat and not zebra? Perhaps you need 'cascading' (dependent) comboboxes on a form.

Comment: In the second table the Field1 and Field2 cells would need to be lookups. The idea is that 001A, 001B and 001C are summarized by the drop down menu. So when 001A is selected, the other fields change to Cat and 1.5. When 001B is selected the other fileds change to mouse and 11. Does that make sense?